# Gitlab: How to deal with caches larger than 5GB with an autoscaled runner with S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gitlab, yocto, gitlab-ci-runner

I configured my yocto project to use an auto-scaled gitlab-runner to run on AWS and now I noticed as the project has grown, that the cache fails to upload every time.

```
Uploading cache.zip to https://build-yocto.s3.amazonaws.com/project/default 
WARNING: Retrying...                               
Uploading cache.zip to https://build-yocto.s3.amazonaws.com/project/default 
FATAL: Received: 400 Bad Request                   
Failed to create cache
```

The cache contains the sstate-cache directory to speed up rebuilds which worked in the beginning like a charm but fails now since (at least thats my conclusion) the sstate-directory has grown to > 10GB.

I saw that S3 has the option for a multipart upload but can't find any options for gitlab-runner to enable this.

Is there any workaround for that issue? like preprocessing the sstate-cache and upload multiple caches?

Comment: We've build a tool that can do the caching on S3. It does multipart uploads, so there is no such limitation, plus there are some other cool features and you can use it outside gilab ci (eg. travis, appveyor, etc):
https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2018/02/cache-ci-builds-to-an-s3-bucket

Answer (score 3):

Gitlab is currently not supporting multipart uploads to S3 so it can only handle caches up to 5GB. But check [this issue/feature proposal](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3524) on that topic before continue reading!

Therefore I built myself a dirty workaround but **be warned! Anyone running a build on that runner can simply print the AWS AccessKey/SecretKey to the build-log!**

Basically I just replicated the pulling and pushing of the cache from S3 and do it manually before and after my buildjob.

In my gitlab runner config.toml I added the following line in the `[[runners]]` section:

```
environment = ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<AccessKey>", "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<SecretKey>", "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=<region>", "AWS_DEFAULT_OUTPUT=<json,text or table>"]
```

That way the evrionment variables are set and aws cli has everything it needs.

In my Dockerfile I needed to add these packages:

```
# Install AWS CLI and tools
RUN apt-get install -y awscli tar pigz
```

The download script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir <path to cache>
aws s3 cp s3://<bucket name>/cache - | pigz -dc | tar -xf - -C <path to cache>
```

The upload script:

```
#!/bin/bash
tar cf - -C <path to cache> . | pigz | aws s3 cp - s3://<bucket name>/cache --expected-size 7516192768
```

`--expected-size` is the aproximate size of the cache. This is required as `aws cp s3` needs to pick a size of the parts of the cache and if it would pick a too small size for the upload it would exceed the maximum limit of parts of the multipart upload. My example used 7GB.

My `.gitlab-ci.yaml` looks now like this:

```
build:
  script:
    - ./download_cache.sh
    - ./build.sh
    - ./upload_cache.sh
```